# Can an ADB backdoor persist after factory reset

Tags: adb, malware

Recently I started playing with automations in my Android device. Specifically, I used Automate, Tasker and MacroDroid. I also downloaded some Tasker plugins, and some ADB connectors for these apps.

A few days after, I noticed weird stuff. For example, apps were being installed automatically overnight. Also, there was this time when I downloaded Twitter and it downloaded 2 apps: the original and a mock app that only had the login page, clearly a phishing attempt. My guess is one of these apps installed a backdoor in my phone and people were sending remote commands to it.

Anyways, I know that ADB is not root access, but I don't actually know the privileges (fs, proc...) it has. How deep can an ADB installed backdoor persist in Android? Could it survive a factory reset? I think I'm about to sell this phone and get a new one, but I don't want to sell it to someone if it has a backdoor, I wouldn't want to harm someone else's privacy.

Comment: A factory reset should be enough. If you want more assurance, flash the stock ROM on your device (just to rule out the possibility that some really evil malacious software has evaded factory reset)//In any case, I would like to sell a phone with stock ROM flashed to give them best experience